# Call Restlet in NetSuite by Name instead of ID

Tags: netsuite, restlet

To externally call an Restlet in NetSuite I use the URL provided in the deployment page.

```
/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=369&deploy=1
```

This however causes lot of work because the InternalID (***369** is this case*) is unique for each customer/environment, hence for each new customer I deploy this restlet to, I need to modify a config file which gets tedious when the number of restlets grows.

I am certain that it is possible to call a restlet via Name (or ID as it is called, see picture below). I stumbled open this information somewhere on the internet about a year ago but for the life of me cant find it again.

### Goal:

To call an restlet via Name, something like this:

```
/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?scriptName=customDeploy_exampleScript&deploy=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the script ID (scriptid) instead of the internal Id for the `script` paramater.

```
/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=customscript_exampleScript&deploy=1
```

Works for deployment ID as well

```
&deploy=customdeploy_exampleScript
```